# SSJS hasOwnProperty returns true for inherited properties

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

To test this in xPages you can use:

```
<xp:text escape="false">
  <xp:this.value>
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:
    (function() {
      var fn = function() {};
      fn.prototype = {prop: "value"};
      var obj = new fn();
      return [
        obj.hasOwnProperty("prop"),
        obj.hasOwnProperty("undefined_prop"),
        obj.hasOwnProperty("toString"),
        obj.hasOwnProperty("constructor")
      ];
    })();
  }]]>
  </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<!-- returns [true, false, true, true] -->
```

To test this in browser you can paste the javascript code to your browsers console.

```
//returns [false, false, false, false] (in browser)
```

Here is quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can  be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Why is xPages SSJS behaviour different from browser?

Comment: Because it's not a browser, and it's not JavaScript. It's a syntax very *similar* to JavaScript that is parsed at runtime into Java objects that have similar behavior. In many cases it appears identical. But at best it's an approximation.

Comment: You are right Tim. Maybe I should just switch to java -.-

Comment: Not necessarily for *all* your code (although, admittedly, I've never regretted doing so). If you can update your question with a specific use case, I may be able to offer an alternative approach that accomplishes the same goal within the context of SSJS.

Comment: @TimTripcony move your comment to an answer, so MUrkina can credit you